# FullCalendar - clientEvents: can't send the returned array to php without losing the date/time values

Tags: php, javascript, json, fullcalendar

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple. When an event is created or resized/moved in the calendar, I update my database. In my database I don't have a row for each event, I have instead a json array in a field which contains all the events for a particular section (that will make sense to you later).

So what I'm trying to do is each time an event is created/resized/moved I get back all the events from the calendar and send them through ajax to the server, and store them in the database. The problem I have is that I lose the date/time information in my php script. I guess it has something to do with the fact that on the javascript side it is encoded differently that on the php side.

I can't update only the event that is resized because in my database, I don't have (yet) a way to differentiate the events. So I need to get them all and make my beautiful json array and put it in the db.

So, anyone get some ideas?
Thx
Guill

Comment: Yea-- its difficult to say what the problem could be - but it is most probably the encoding- if you search for fullcalender date problem you will realise that the encoding has to be perfect. Though! the new version is more flexible! Post at least the data that is going to PHP and what is comming out from PHP.. otherwise i can pole my finger in the air and guess till I..

Comment: We'll need to see some code, examples, the works.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the lack of info. 
I actually did find something and post it but it was refused coz I'm a stackoverflow n00b.
I was making the mistake (I guess) to post the javascript array returned by clientEvents. Now I'm posting the JSON string of the array and of course I receive the data "correctly" in the php script. Just "correctly" because the times are wrong, but that's another story and I do have an idea of where to look further.
Thx again!

Comment: So if you receive the JSON from fullcalendar - the times are incorrect? How do you post the JSON- do you serialize the array somehow? Can you just post a comment here of a snippet of json near the time. Just after its serialized and before PHP gets it..

Comment: couldn't use the stack markdown, so you can get a well formatted snippet here: https://gist.github.com/973961  The first console.log returns a date like **Mon Sep 05 2011 22:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)**, the second (with the JSON.stringify) returns a date like **2011-08-30T11:00:00.000Z**.

Comment: Ok I got something working. The dates in my db are in unix timestamp format and fullcalendar will add the correct timezone. But when I get the dates back with the clientEvents method, I have to make some manipulation because the dates returned are not correct, I think. They don't take the browser timezone in consideration. I filled a bug report. I think the dates returned should be like: **2011-09-06T11:00:00.000+00:00** instead of **2011-09-06T11:00:00.000Z**.  
Thanks

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and then accept it.